# Recursively find ebooks that match all the search strings

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, search

I have few pdf, epub, mobi files. I want to find all files which have the words:

- all-or-nothing
- pervasive
- catastrophizing

I mean all words have to be present in the file. They do not need to be in the same line, paragraph or page.

I might also use search terms which have space.

Currently I use the command

```
rga 'all-or-nothing' --ignore-case --files-with-matches \
| xargs -I{} rga 'pervasive' --ignore-case --files-with-matches "{}" \
| xargs -I{} rga 'catastrophizing' --ignore-case --files-with-matches "{}"
```

It has few issues:

- xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
- This command does not give same result on same files when run multiple times.

What might be a better solution here.

**Update 1:**

What I found so far is:

```
comm -12 <(rga 'A1' --ignore-case --files-with-matches | sort) \
<(rga 'A2' --ignore-case --files-with-matches | sort) \
| comm -12 - <(rga 'A3' --ignore-case --files-with-matches | sort) \
| comm -12 - <(rga 'A4' --ignore-case --files-with-matches | sort)
```

Still looking for a more performant solution as this one run `rga` four times.

Comment: I wasn't able to install `rga` in MS WSL ubuntu environment. Can you provide some information about that?